# reactjs service worker update

Tags: service-worker, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA made by create-react-app.
I have service worker enabled as by default.

```
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker'
import App from './App'
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />
  , document.getElementById('root'))
registerServiceWorker()
```

On every publish I change package version, but my service-worker doesn't update.

I have tried with function

```
import { unregister } from './registerServiceWorker';
unregister()
```

as described here [https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#making-a-progressive-web-app)

And this

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations()
  .then(registrationsArray => {
    if (registrationsArray.length > 0) {
        registrationsArray[0].update()
    }
  })
```

It doesn't work, what is my mistake? What is wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Update to `react-scripts` ^3.2.0.  Verify that you have the new version of serviceWorker.ts or .js.  The old one was called `registerServiceWorker.ts` and the register function did not accept a configuration object.  Here is the new one:  https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/3190e4f4a99b8c54acb0993d92fec8a859889a28/packages/cra-template/template/src/serviceWorker.js
Note that this solution only works well if you are Not lazy-loading.

then in index.tsx:

```
  serviceWorker.register({
    onUpdate: registration => {
      alert('New version available!  Ready to update?');
      if (registration && registration.waiting) {
        registration.waiting.postMessage({ type: 'SKIP_WAITING' });
      }
      window.location.reload();
    }
  });
```

The latest version of the ServiceWorker.ts `register()`function accepts a config object with a callback function where we can handle upgrading.  If we post a message `SKIP_WAITING` this tells the service worker to stop waiting and to go ahead and load the new content after the next refresh.  In this example I am using a javascript alert to inform the user.  Please replace this with a custom toast.

The reason this `postMessage` function works is because under the hood CRA is using `workbox-webpack-plugin` which includes a `SKIP_WAITING` listener.

**More About Service Workers**

good guide: https://redfin.engineering/how-to-fix-the-refresh-button-when-using-service-workers-a8e27af6df68

CRA issue discussing service worker cache:  https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5316

If you are not using CRA, you can use workbox directly: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox